# Excel VBA filter for multiple case independent "Contains" criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter column E (column has text values) for any value that contains any of the values from the list ("ALL", "SUPER", "EXTRA") and the filter should be case independent. For example filter should retain "Fall", "fAll", "FaLL" (case independent for "ALL") and "Dextra".

Somehow I could not do it with UI. Row by row checking with instring is the last option but if done by VBA filter it would better suit the present work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: 365, I'm looking more for a VBA solution

Comment: Try placing that column in an array, build another array an fill it by iteration, placing a marker ("OK", for instance), then drop the array content on column after the last one and filter by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code, which puts in practice my sugestions from the above comment. It should be fast enough, even for a large range. All processing is done in memory, only the markers array is dropped at once, at the end of the code, followed by filtering on it. This solution assumes that **the headers exist in the sheet first row**:

```
Sub filterByPartialStrins()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, colMark As Range, lastR As Long, lastC As Long
   Dim arrCrit(), arr, arrMark, El, i As Long
   Const markName As String = "Marker_column"
   
   arrCrit = Array("ALL", "SUPER", "EXTRA") 'place partial criteria in an array
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   If sh.AutoFilterMode Then sh.AutoFilterMode = False 'eliminate the filter, if any
   
   lastR = sh.Range("E" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
   
   'determinte the column where the marker to be placed:
   Set colMark = sh.rows(1).Find(What:=markName, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
   If Not colMark Is Nothing Then
        lastC = colMark.column  'for the case when the marker column exists
   Else
        lastC = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column + 1 'next empty column if marker column does not exist
   End If
   
   arr = sh.Range("E2:E" & lastR).Value2       'place E:E column in an array for faster processing
   ReDim arrMark(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'ReDim the array to keep markers
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For Each El In arrCrit
            'place a marker if the necessary condition is true:
            If InStr(1, arr(i, 1), El, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then arrMark(i, 1) = "OK": Exit For
        Next El
   Next
   
   If colMark Is Nothing Then sh.cells(1, lastC).Value = markName 'place the marker column name, IF NOT EXISTS
   
   'dropo the arrMark content, at once:
   sh.cells(2, lastC).Resize(UBound(arrMark), 1).Value2 = arrMark
   
   'filter by the marker column
   sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter lastC, "OK"
   
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```